# sap.m.List - change model on itemPress

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have sap.m.List with sap.m.StandardListItem within oDialog. When user opens oDialog, model is being set with main category list. Item press sets second model with child items, but List control showing blank items, first model is still set as default. What I'm doing wrong?

My code (oList):

```
  var oList = new sap.m.List({
        mode: "SingleSelectMaster",
        templateShareable: false,
        includeItemInSelection: true,
        itemPress: function (oEvent) {
            var sPath = oList.getSelectedItem().getBindingContext().sPath.substr(1);
            var sListID = oList.getId();

            var model = oList.getModel().getData();
            console.log("model current (press): ", model);
          
            //check item type
            var sItemType = oList.getSelectedItem().mProperties.type;
       
            if (sItemType == "Active") {
                    //do somtehing
            }
            

            //new model - child items
            var sURL = '/XMII/Runner?Transaction=Project/trasnaction&param1=' + param1;
            var oModel3 = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();
            oModel3.loadData(sURL,"Model" + sPath, false);
               
         
           
           oList.setModel(oModel3, "Model" + sPath);
           oList.setBindingContext(new sap.ui.model.Context(oModel3,  "Model" + sPath + ">/serviceInvocationResponse/responses"));
           oList.bindItems({
                            path: "/",
                            templateShareable: false,
                            template: oTemplate
                        });
        

            
            var newData = oList.getModel("Model" + sPath).getProperty("/"); //showing correct data from new model
            console.log("newData: ", newData);

            if (sItemType == "Navigation") {
                    //do somtehing
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm using SAP UI5 ver. 1.44.46

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I could not really understand what you are trying to achieve. However, I spot something which might help. On your `oList.bindItems` call, you are not passing the model name and as a consequence it's using the default model. This is an aggregation binding and you can provide the model name inside the `path` like `path:modelName>/`or in a attribute called `model` without the `>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have two models: 1 - main category list; 2 - child items. On first open, list display items from first model. On item press I want to set 2 model with child items. My question is how to achive that? Maybe my aproach is not good?

Comment: I strongly suggest you to create another list then. Trying to reuse it just makes the process harder.

Comment: @fabiopagoti Thanks for the hint. I created two lists: for the master model and the child model. Now it works the way I wanted.